# OpenCV Libraries in Hadoop

Tags: java, opencv, hadoop

I wrote one simple application in which I am using OpenCV. I put all the jar files in /usr/local/hadoop/lib folder. While running the hadoop job, I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$CvArr
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:399)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$CvArr
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1486)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1456)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1545)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:686)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:333)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:231)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvArr
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 15 more

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: can you show, how you run the hadoop job?

Comment: This is how I am trying to execute: ./bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/MyApp.jar MainProc /examples/inputfile /usr/local/output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the option `libjars` when running the hadoop job. Try the following:

```
hadoop jar yourjar.jar MainClass -libjars /path/to/external/jar
```

More information [here](http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/).

Comment: The problem is I have an Input and Output argument while executing hadoop job. If I add -libjars then the system says that it needs one input and one output.

Comment: Does it work if you add the input and the output folder after `-libjars /path/to/external/jar`?

Comment: No it does not. Here is what i am inputting now: ./bin/hadoop jar /usr/local/v.jar MainProc -libjars /us
r/local/hadoop/lib/javacpp.jar /examples/input /usr/local/output
And this is what my system says when arguments are not 2: Usage: MainProc <input path> <output path>

Comment: And if you add them before the `-libjars` option?

Comment: The same error (Usage: MainProc <input path> <output path>) because arguments are more than two.

Comment: Then I don't know the solution... You can try with `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/path/to/jar` before running `hadoop jar` (without `-libjars`).

Comment: Thanks. I was able to remove that error. But now I have having another error: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_core in java.library.path. Any idea about this?

Comment: That error has nothing to do with the original question. Please create a new thread with that error and if the answer helped you solve the error you had when you wrote the question please accept it.